# Why is every non-zero element not a unit of this ring?

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=a+b\sqrt2$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, if I am understanding the definition of units correctly, they are all the elements within the ring that have multiplicative inverses. So for example, the element $1+\sqrt2$ has the multiplicative inverse $-1+\sqrt2$, so we can say that they are both units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=a+b\sqrt2$.

So my question is, wouldn't every element of the ring be a unit then, except for the case when $a=b=0$?

Comment: What's the inverse of $2$?

Comment: Oh my goodness, this is possibly the most embarrassing thing to happen to me for a while. Cheers mate.

Comment: happens to the best of us, no worries.

Comment: As an extension, does this mean that if I have say $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ similarly defined but $a$ nonzero, then it will have no units? Because the inverse would be $\frac{a-b\sqrt{-2}}{a^2+2b}$, but the real component can never be an integer since $a^2+2b>a$?

Comment: That should be $a^2+2b^2$ in the denominator. The only units are $\pm 1$; if $b \neq 0$, then $a^2+2b^2>1$. If $b=0$, then $a^2$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z$ iff $a = \pm 1$.